# Wrap angular $resource requests not returning POST data

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs

I'm working on wrapping my $resource requests in a simple wrapper. The main idea
is to be able to add some logic before the request is made. I've followed the nice article written by [Nils](http://nils-blum-oeste.net/angularjs-send-auth-token-with-every--request/#.URYyLVpU5r0).

Here you can see a service definition to access the REST API module.

```
resources.factory('Device', ['RequestWrapper', '$resource', 'lelylan.config', function(RequestWrapper, $http, config) {
  var resource = $resource(config.endpoint + '/devices/:id', { id: '@id' });
  return RequestWrapper.wrap(resource, ['get', 'query', 'save', 'delete']);
}]);
```

And here you can see the request wrapper definition.

```
resources.factory('RequestWrapper', ['AccessToken', function(AccessToken) {
  var requestWrapper = {};
  var token;

  requestWrapper.wrap = function(resource, actions) {
    token = AccessToken.initialize();

    var wrappedResource = resource;
    for (var i=0; i < actions.length; i++) { request(wrappedResource, actions[i]); };
    return wrappedResource;
  };

  var request = function(resource, action) {
    resource['_' + action]  = resource[action];

    resource[action] = function(param, data, success, error) {
      (AccessToken.get().access_token) ? setAuthorizationHeader() : deleteAuthorizationHeader()
      return resource['_' + action](param, data, success, error);
    };
  };

  var setAuthorizationHeader = function() {
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token.access_token;
  };

  var deleteAuthorizationHeader = function() {
    delete $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']
  };

  return requestWrapper;
}]);
```

Everything works just fine for the GET and DELETE methods (the ones that does not returns 
a body seems), but I can't get $save working. What happens is that when the JSON of the 
created resources returns it is not added. I have only the data I've set on the creation
phase. Let me make an example.

In this case we use the wrapped resource. If I try to get the #updated_at attribute I can't
see it. In the Chrome inspector I can see how the resource is successfully created.

```
$scope.device = new Device({ name: 'Angular light', type: 'http://localhost:9000/types/50bf5af4d033a95486000002' });
$scope.device.$save(function(){ console.log('Device Wrapped', $scope.device.created_at) });
# => undefined
```

If I use $resource everything works fine.

```
// Suppose authorization is already set
var Resource = $resource('http://localhost\\:9000/devices/:id');
$scope.resource = new Resource({ name: 'Angular light', type: 'http://localhost:9000/types/50bf5af4d033a95486000002' });
$scope.resource.$save(function(){ console.log('Device Base', $scope.resource.created_at); });
# => 2013-02-09T12:26:01Z
```

I started to check the angular-resource.js code but after few hours I couldn't really figure
it out. I can't get why the body is returned, but in the wrapper resource it is not accessible.

Any idea or help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

While diving into AngularJS source code I've found the solution.

The problem was that the wrapper was returning a function instead of an object and this was giving some problems. The solution is to change the following row in the Wrapper:

```
return resource['_' + action](param, data, success, error);
```

with this one:

```
return resource['_' + action].call(this, params, data, success, error);
```

Why? The fast answer is because in the source code of angular-resource they use it. Actually #call run the function sending this to the calling object. It is often used to initialize an object. [Learn more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).